# getting "localhost didn’t send any data" in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, flask

I created a Flask API and dockerized it. When I run `docker run -p 9999:8000 urban-dictionary-api-unofficial`. It runs perfectly and can be accessed via my browser. However, I created a Kubernetes deployment for it which allows more pods to run, but after doing so, it is unable to be accessed. Below are the files used for the deployment.

deployments.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial-deployment
  labels:
    app: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial
          image: n1nja0p/urban-dictionary-api-unofficial
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
```

services.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial-service
  labels:
    app: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9999
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: urban-dictionary-api-unofficial
  sessionAffinity: None
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["pip","install","flask","bs4","requests"]
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python","src/main.py"]
```

However, I'm getting an error when trying to access it through my browser:

[image: the error]

What did I do wrong?

Edit :

Output of `kubectl get service urban-dictionary-api-unofficial-service`:

```
NAME                                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
urban-dictionary-api-unofficial-service   LoadBalancer   10.99.186.186   localhost     9999:31048/TCP   3h10m
```

Comment: you need to use load balancer's public IP address instead of localhost as you're using `Service` of type of `LoadBalancer`.

Comment: the external IP address of `LoadBalancer` is `localhost` only.

Comment: can you add the output of `kubectl get svc urban-dictionary-api-unofficial-service` in your post?

Comment: replace internal port `9999` with node port `31048` and then try.

Comment: it didn't work. btw, are you on discord?

Comment: not on discord.

Comment: hey @TaimoorMirza, I deleted my image and pushed it again. After redeploying it on the cluster, I am now able to access it through the browser. Thank you